# Convert GIcon into GdkPixbuf

Tags: gtk, gdk, gdkpixbuf

I'm using the GAppInfo/GDesktopAppInfo.

`GIcon *icon = gtk_app_info_get_icon (G_APP_INFO(appinfo));`

Now I need to put it on a GtkIconView but I found that there is no way to create a GdkPixbuf from GIcon. Anyone knows this? Thanks very much!

**EDIT 1:** Actually it's GThemedIcon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GIcon.html):

> GIcon does not provide the actual pixmap for the icon as this is out of GIO's scope, however implementations of GIcon may contain the name of an icon (see GThemedIcon), or the path to an icon (see GLoadableIcon).

However, knowing icon name may facilitate in obtaining actual pixmap. For example, [file-roller](http://fileroller.sourceforge.net/) project uses the following function to obtain pixbuf from *GtkIconTheme* and *GThemedIcon*:

```
GdkPixbuf *
get_icon_pixbuf (GtkIconTheme *icon_theme,
         GThemedIcon  *icon,
         int           size) 
{
    char        **icon_names;
    GtkIconInfo  *icon_info;
    GdkPixbuf    *pixbuf;
    GError       *error = NULL;

    g_object_get (icon, "names", &icon_names, NULL);

    icon_info = gtk_icon_theme_choose_icon (icon_theme, (const char **)icon_names, size, 0);
    pixbuf = gtk_icon_info_load_icon (icon_info, &error);
    if (pixbuf == NULL) {
        g_warning ("could not load icon pixbuf: %s\n", error->message);
        g_clear_error (&error);
    }

    gtk_icon_info_free (icon_info);
    g_strfreev (icon_names);

    return pixbuf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following code for how to get icons file from GIcon:

```
GtkIconInfo *pGtkIconInfo;
Gicon *pgIcon=gtk_app_info_get_icon (G_APP_INFO(appinfo));

GtkIconTheme *pGtkIconTheme= gtk_icon_theme_get_default();
pGtkIconInfo=gtk_icon_theme_lookup_by_gicon(pGtkIconTheme,pgIcon,256,GTK_ICON_LOOKUP_USE_BUILTIN);

//get icon filename if icone 256*256 exist.

printf("%s\n",gtk_icon_info_get_filename(pGtkIconInfo));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should mark the code part as edit.