# How to get a gdk_pixbuf from a GIcon

Tags: gtk

I have created a a GIcon with emblem:

```
icon = g_themed_icon_new("folder");
emblem_icon = g_themed_icon_new("emblem_symbolic_link");
emblem = g_emblem_new(emblem_icon);
emblemed = g_emblemed_icon_new(icon, emblem);
```

I would now like to get this GIcon as as a pixbuf. The way would seem to be gtk_icon_info_load_icon(), but I do not see any way to get the GtkIconInfo.

Does anyone have a solution?

I have tried going via a GtkImage, but that does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert GIcon into GdkPixbuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060387/convert-gicon-into-gdkpixbuf)

Comment: Thanks, but the GtkIconInfo is being obtained from gtk_icon_theme_choose_icon(). I already have the GIcon, and need to get GtkIconInfo from that.

Comment: There's [gtk_icon_theme_lookup_by_gicon](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.IconTheme.lookup_by_gicon.html) if you have a GIcon instead of the icon name

Comment: Check out this thread: https://discourse.gnome.org/t/get-a-list-of-mounted-devices/13962/14